# How to use cache to reduce sympy symbolic calculation problems?

Tags: python, caching, hash, sympy, symbols

```
import sympy as sp
from fuanctools import lru_cache

s = []
for i in range(4):
    s.append(sp.Symbol('s%s'%i)

@lru_cache
def some_calculation(input1, input2):
    '''
    some calculation code
    '''
    return calculation_result

#First calculation
some_calculation(sp.sin(s[0]),sp.sin(s[1]))
#Second calculation
some_calculation(sp.sin(s[2]),sp.sin(s[3]))
```

In the second calculation, it differs from the first only in variables. The actual calculation process is the same. In the current method, it has a different dependent variable, so it will need to be re-calculated. How to use the cache method, so that the calculation process does not have to be repeated, without changing the calculation results.

P.S. The calculation here is to preserve the original form of the variable, not the numerical solution after the substitution. Here are some examples:

```
def example_calculation(input1, input2):
    return sp.simplify(input1(input1+input2) + input2(input1-input2))
```

I want a more general approach. The input1 and input2 are random input. Before using cache, it is necessary to first judge input1 and input2 that have appeared the same structure. Make sure that there has been a calculation of the same structure before taking advantage of the direct output of the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting a symbolic result by passing Symbol `x` and `y` to the calculation and then that result, in a sense, *is* your cache. Just substitute in the values you want as replacement for the `x` and `y`.

```py
def f(x,y):
  return x + y

from sympy.abc import x, y
from sympy import symbols
s = symbols('s:4')
v = f(x, y)

>>> v
x + y
>>> v.subs(dict(zip((x,y),(s[0],s[1]))))
s0 + s1
```

or more complicated `f`:

```py
def f(x,y):
  g, h = map(Function, 'gh')
  return g(x + y) + h(x - y)

s=symbols('s:5')
C=lambda i,j: cos(s[i])*cos(s[j]);S=lambda i,j: sin(s[i])*sin(s[j])

>>> eq = f(x, y); eq
g(x + y) + h(x - y)
>>> eq.subs(x,S(0,1)).subs(y,C(2,4))
g(sin(s0)*sin(s1) + cos(s2)*cos(s4)) + h(sin(s0)*sin(s1) - cos(s2)*cos(s4))
>>> eq.subs(x,S(1,2)).subs(y,C(3,4))
g(sin(s1)*sin(s2) + cos(s3)*cos(s4)) + h(sin(s1)*sin(s2) - cos(s3)*cos(s4))
```

If using `subs` bothers you, go ahead and lambdify your equation to do the subs/xreplace for you:

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import a, b
>>> EQ = lambdify((a,b), eq.xreplace(dict(zip((x,y),(a,b)))))
>>> EQ(S(1,2), C(3,4))
g(sin(s1)*sin(s2) + cos(s3)*cos(s4)) + h(sin(s1)*sin(s2) - cos(s3)*cos(s4))
```

Comment: In your example, both input and computation are simply parseable. If the input is more complex, eg the input is sin(s0)sin(s1) and cos(s2)cos(s4). The calculation is input1(input1+input2) + input2(input1-input2). Next, there are new inputs such as sin(s1)sin(s2) and cos(s3)cos(s4), so how to judge that the input structures of the two are the same, so you can directly use the cache to output the result, and then replace it back to the original The answer that should be given?

Comment: Assuming you meant `func1(input1+input2)`, etc..., I don't see the complication. I updated to show that the principle is the same: let `x` and `y` represent the two inputs and replace them with whatever the inputs really. `x` and `y` are the placeholders in your arbitrarily complicated result of your function that accepts two inputs.

Comment: Your second answer is close to what I want, but I want a more general approach. The (x,y) in f(x,y) is a random input. Just take C=lambda i, j: cos(s[i])*cos(s[j]); S=lambda i, j: sin(s[i])*sin(s[j]). Before performing eq.subs(), it is necessary to first judge x and y that have appeared the same structure. Make sure that there has been a calculation of the same structure before taking advantage of the direct output of the cache.

Comment: see updated ans